# \hhline doesn't show double line

Tags: tables

I've got a template that I have to work with. In that I want to use `\hhline`. But everytime I want to draw a double line with `\hhline{=}` no line at all appears. How an I fix this?

Minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setlength{\doublerulesep}{0pt}
\usepackage{multirow} % Multirows in tabulars
\usepackage{longtable, tabu} % Flexible tabulars i.e. page breaks and horizontal fill
\usepackage{hhline} % Custom hlines
\newtabulinestyle{mydashline=on 1.5pt off 2pt}
\tabulinesep=1mm

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{| >{\centering}m{0.1\textwidth} | >{\centering}m{0.2\textwidth} | >{\centering}m{0.2\textwidth} | >{\centering}m{0.1\textwidth} | >{\centering}m{0.1\textwidth} | >{\centering}m{0.1\textwidth} |}
    \hhline{------}
    A & B & C, D & E & F & G \tabularnewline \hhline{======}
    0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 3 \tabularnewline \hhline{------}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 3 \tabularnewline \hhline{------}
    2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 3 \tabularnewline \hhline{------}
    3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 3 \tabularnewline \hhline{------}
    4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 3 \tabularnewline \hhline{------}
    5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 3 \tabularnewline \hhline{------}
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Remove `\setlength{\doublerulesep}{0pt}` from your preamble.

Comment: And welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Thanks that is the solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behaviour is caused by setting the separation between double rules to `0pt`. If you remove `\setlength{\doublerulesep}{0pt}` from your preamble everything should work fine again.